# Численное решение уравнения колебания волны методом сеток С++

Tags: c++, double, численные-методы

Согласно заданию, мне необходимо решить уравнение колебания волны методом сеток. Для метода был написан код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double (*p) (double);
double (*q) (double);
double (*f) (double);
double (*g) (double);

double _p(double t)
{return 0.0;}

double _q (double t)
{return 2*(t + 1);}

double _f (double x)
{return x*(x + 1);}

double _g (double x)
{return cos(x);}

const int n = 20;
const int m = 200;

int main()
{
    p = _p;
    q = _q;
    f = _f;
    g = _g;

    double h = 0.05;
    double k = 0.025;
    double lmbd = k/h;
    double x0 = 0;
    double xk = 1;
    double t0 = 0;
    double tk = 5;

    double U[n][m]; //матрица

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        U[i][0] = f(x0 + i*h);
        U[i][1] = U[i][0] + k*g(x0 + i*h);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        U[0][j] = p(t0 + j*k);

    U[20][0] = g(0.0);

    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
        U[20][j] = q(t0 + j*k);

    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
        for(int i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
            U[i][j+1] = 2*(1 - lmbd*lmbd)*U[i][j] + lmbd*lmbd*(U[i+1][j] + U[i-1][j]) - U[i][j-1];

    cout << "\nТочки для t = 0" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x0 + i*h << "  " << U[i][0] << endl;

    cout << "\nТочки для t = 3" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x0 + i*h << "  " << U[i][120] << endl;

    cout << "\nТочки для t = 5" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x0 + i*h << "  " << U[i][200] << endl;

    cout << "\nТочки для x = 0.3" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cout << t0 + j*k << "  " << U[6][j] << endl;

    cout << "\nТочки для x = 0.5" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cout << t0 + j*k << "  " << U[10][j] << endl;

    cout << "\nТочки для x = 0.7" << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        cout << t0 + j*k << "  " << U[14][j] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

После запуска на экран выводятся числа выходящие за допустимый диапазон (для  t это [0: 5], а для х — [0; 1]). Думаю, что проблема в нахождении произведения целого и дробного чисел, как например:

```
double h = 0.05;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    U[i][0] = f(x0 + i*h);
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, где я ошибаюсь. Может, в самом методе? Или проблема в чем-то другом?

[image: Ошибка вывода]

Comment: Проблема точно не в произведении целого и дробного числа, запустите в отладчике и посмотрите что происходит

Comment: Вот здесь: `cout << x0 + i*h << "  " << U[i][200] ` на выходе будет мусор, ибо у массива нет индекса 200, есть только 199. Это первое, что в глаза бросается. И, конечно, это не причина неправильного вывода из скриншота (там уже другой цикл).

Comment: Перед последним циклом мы имеем: `m = 200      k = 6.35        t0 = 2.05`. Т.е. за время работы программы Вы где-то портите начальные данные.

Comment: Еще поймал: `U[20][j] = q(t0 + j*k);` - та же проблема, должно быть 19, а не 20. И это именно здесь все портится. Ну и ` U[20][0] = g(0.0);`

Comment: @Fqqlt спасибо за помощь. После исправлений вывод стал заметно лучше.

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо за помощь. Все упомянутые ошибки исправила.

Comment: Я нашел еще одну такого же типа... но не такую очевидную... `U[i][j+1] = 2*(1 - lmbd*lmbd)...` - в цикле до `m` индекс `j+1` превратится в 200... Напрашивается сделать внешний цикл до `m-1`.

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо за ещё одно замечание. При проверке не учла это. Сейчас буду смотреть, как поведёт себя функция на графике.